# Cannot connect to websocket server ssl

Tags: python, ssl

Can you help me figure out the error I encountered when attempting to use Let's Encrypt certificates obtained for Apache2 to encrypt my WebSocket server with SSL? I extracted the certificates from Apache and replaced the server settings with them, but an error occurred that I can't understand.
python 3.8

```
`
    from websocket_server import WebsocketServer
    
    
    
    class MyWebSocketServer:
        def __init__(self, host, port, user, password, db):
    
            ssl_cert = "cert.pem"
            ssl_key = "privkey.pem"
            self.server = WebsocketServer(port=port, host=host, key=ssl_key, cert=ssl_cert)
            self.server.set_fn_new_client(self.on_new_client)
            self.server.set_fn_message_received(self.on_message)
            self.server.set_fn_client_left(self.on_client_left)

`
```

but when i connect by wss on server i got error:

```
`
    WARNING:websocket_server.websocket_server:SSL not available (are the paths ../privkey.pem and ../fullchain.pem correct for the key and cert?)
    Client disconnected
    ----------------------------------------
    Exception happened during processing of request from ('94.25.174.29', 8512)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 683, in process_request_thread
        self.finish_request(request, client_address)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 360, in finish_request
        self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websocket_server/websocket_server.py", line 271, in __init__
        StreamRequestHandler.__init__(self, socket, addr, server)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.8/socketserver.py", line 747, in __init__
        self.handle()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websocket_server/websocket_server.py", line 282, in handle
        self.handshake()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websocket_server/websocket_server.py", line 430, in handshake
        headers = self.read_http_headers()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/websocket_server/websocket_server.py", line 418, in read_http_headers
        http_get = self.rfile.readline().decode().strip()
    UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfc in position 8: invalid start byte

`
```

fullchain and privkey i got from letsslencrypt for apache and copy this files in directory with python script

This is my client

```
`
    <script>
    var sock = new WebSocket("wss://api:port");
    sock.onopen = function() {
      //alert("Соединение установлено.");
    };
    
    sock.onclose = function(event) {
      if (event.wasClean) {
        //alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
      } else {
       // alert('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
      }
      //alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
    };
    
    sock.onmessage = function(event) {
      //alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
      console.log(event.data);
    };
    
    sock.onerror = function(error) {
      //alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
    };
    </script>
`
```